# How to add default `jvm` sourceSet to `android` target in Kotlin Multiplatform?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

With Kotlin/Multiplatform **1.3.11** i had the following `build.gradle`:

```
    fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'jvm')
    fromPreset(presets.android, 'jvm') // reusing jvm sources for android platform impl
```

So basically i wanted to reuse all code for `jvm` target for `android` target.

With just-released Kotlin/Multiplatform **1.3.20** now i'm getting an error:

> The target 'jvm' already exists, but it was not created with the 'android' preset. To configure it, access it by name in `kotlin.targets` or use the preset function 'jvm'
>   Open File

I've tried to migrate to new syntax:

```
   jvm()
   android() {
   sourceSets.add(kotlin.targets.jvm.compilations.main.defaultSourceSet)
   }
```

but it does not reuse jvm defaultSourceSet for Android target:

> Expected class 'URL' has no actual declaration in module

so it does not use default jvm sourceset actually and not throwing Groovy syntax error.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the best solution is to have some common sourceset and one for each platform:

```
    commonJvmMain {
        dependencies {
            implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
        }
    }
    jvmMain {
        dependsOn commonJvmMain
    }
    androidMain {
        dependsOn commonJvmMain
    }
```

Put shared code in `commonJvmMain` sourceset directory.

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2577